# jQuery: How to secure timer

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, timer

I 'm making quiz app that has a timer. The user needs to answer a number of questions for a limited time
What is the best way to secure timer from hacker attacks? (changing Javascript code)
Is there a good server-side (PHP) solution to check time after counting?

example timer code:

```
<div id="timer"></div>
<script>
var currentTime = 200;

var tajmer = setInterval(timer, 100);

function timer() {
    currentTime = currentTime - 1;    
    $('#timer').text(currentTime / 10);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Validation is done server side - log users start time somewhere serverside (probably database). When they submit answer, check current time - start time, if its over the allotted period, give zero points. Still keep the js timer for user experience.

Comment: use sessions and store start-time in them